# Web-scraping in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data such as

**Date of Incorporation,
Email Address,Address and Director Details**
From a list of 500 websites which is in **https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list/nic-300-company.html** which extends into pages.
I need to extract websites, which i have done using Power query in excel, but then to extract specific details from each website is a tedious work in Power Query.

Also,the issue lies in the Email Address and Address, unable to find a class/tag ID name.(This i have got recently from the help below).

[image]

**Please guide me.**

This is a simple code, because i found everything clearly.
This code has nothing to do with the doubt asked.

```
Set webpage = ie.document
Set mtbl = webpage.getElementsByTagName("Table")(1)
Set table_data = mtbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following attempt should fetch you the email id along with the address from that site:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL = "https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/TECHDRIVE-SOFTWARE-LIMITED/U30007DL1999PLC356280"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, adr As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each elem In Html.getElementsByTagName("b")
        If InStr(elem.innerText, "Email ID:") > 0 Then
            [A1] = elem.ParentNode.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next elem

    For Each adr In Html.getElementsByTagName("b")
        If InStr(adr.innerText, "Address:") > 0 Then
            [B1] = adr.ParentNode.NextSibling.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next adr
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.
Small request,
 I have around 500 websites, if i need to loop them over this code, where would i do it ?
And also if i need those to be scraped over different cells in excel , then how would i do it ?
Do i have to use the (Endx1Up)